# Minimizing Customer Interruption During Deployment

Tags: java, session, terracotta

How do you deploy new code into production so that the customer experience is not interrupted?

Let's assume an e-commerce website that's in a load balanced environment, where no session state is shared.  Tomcat is the application server.

The only ideas I can come up with are (1) use JavaRebel, but I have no experience with this and don't know what could go wrong (maybe session object mismatch, for example if you remove a member from a class)  (2) have real-time monitoring of where your users are in the shopping experience and prevent new items from being added to the cart; wait until all existing shoppers have completed their order or have expired; then turn off the server and deploy new code.

Any ideas?  Or is this a situation where it's critical to share session data among the web servers with something like terracotta?  Then again, how do you deploy new code to the web servers where a session's object member has been removed or added?

Comment: To those requesting a close on this question, how is this of topic?  The FAQ states I can ask "matters that are unique to the programming profession".

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but deployment is usually a concern of sysadmin/operations rather than developers, so Server Fault may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Common approaches I've seen:

- if there's not much state then store it client-side, in a cookie - this also has the advantage of not requiring IP affinity so requests can be distributed more evenly
- shared storage (DB, Terracotta, etc.) - obviously this can become a bottleneck
- deploy at a quiet time and hope nobody notices
- remove server from pool for new sessions, then monitor the logs and wait for requests to die off

Answer (score 1):

A common approach is to take one server at a time out of the load balancing pool, deploy the new code to it, and then put it back into the pool.

Comment: But doing this blindly causes the users to jump to the next available web server that does not have their session information.